# Clang-format: Always wrap function signature (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, format, clang, clang-format

At work, we have a specific convention on how to format function signatures.

In summary:

- Always wrapped
- Opening argument bracket on a new line
- One function argument per line
- Closing argument bracket on a new line
- Opening function body bracket on a new line

Example:

```c
void my_func
(
    int arg1,
    char arg2
)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

Is there a way to configure `clang-format` to format signatures like this? Or if not, at least tell it to not change the function signatures when formatting.

EDIT: I am also open to other formatters, as long as they can achieve what I am after.

Comment: @0___________ It does have uses - such as early in the development cycle with functions that have a lot of arguments that are likely to change as the code fills out.  It's easier to "see" and update arguments when they're formatted like this.  It does take some getting used to, though.

Comment: I think you just have to do the digging yourself: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: I'm a renegade myself, but I'm sort of militant about coders using *common* coding styles; that is, styles that a typical C++ coder will recognize.  This isn't one of those styles.

Comment: I'm not here for a debate people. For better or for worse our codebase (which is huge) uses this formatting for function signatures. People in the company are used to it. I looked over the configuration options but I didn't see a way to do either, which is why I am asking here.

Comment: The thing is: One would have to dig deep into the documentation to figure your explicit requirements out. And that takes time. If you think that someone can swing a magic wand and provide you the correct file.. the chance of that is pretty low. And I don't think someone wants such a tremendous time investment for something like this. (I might be wrong and you might get lucky)

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri I've often been surprised by how often questions here reveal magic wands...

Comment: I'm afraid it may not be possible. There's no option to break before open parenthesis and clang-format will only break parameter list if it doesn't fit in one line. You could attempt to set column limit to  `1`, but that will likely have consequences in other places in code. I don't know of any option to ignore all declarations either (unless we count "not formatting header files").

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri You basically described the entire Stack Exchange operation. People spend their time for useless Internet Points (a.k.a "reputation" and "badges") and their own satisfaction. Your opinion whether the given question has good chance of getting answers is completely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect with such a style, you'll have to write the style file yourself. Normally one would take a given file (Mozilla, etc.) and modify tiny bits.

Anyway, this here
[Clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)
states, that the `BAS_BlockIndent` feature does at least part of your function definition. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, looks like this only breaks if the arguments do not fit on a line:
> Always break after an open bracket, if the parameters don’t fit on a single line.